# The quantity of provided keys does not match the expected value

Tags: sapui5

Getting the above error when trying a read on me Mockserver oData....

MockServer: Invalid key predicate. The quantity of provided keys does not match the expected value

```
this.getModel().read("/CalendarSet(ShopId='" + oArgs.siteId + "')", {
   success: function (oData) {
   console.log(oData);
   }.bind(this),
   error: function (oError) {
    console.log("error");
   }.bind(this)
})
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I can imagine your OData entity has a combined key, but you are only giving one (the `ShopId`). It is hard to say without seeing the OData metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I used a filtering method which resolved the problem.